# Trouble using g++ after upgrading to lion/ new xcode

Tags: macos, g++, osx-lion

Just upgraded to Lion from SL, and downloaded xCode from app store.

I go to compile "Hello World" and find that g++ isn't being found.  After some searching,  I find it in /Developer/usr/bin.   I add this to my path, and try to compile, and now its saying it can't find iostream.

Clearly, I missed some key setup step but I don't seem to know what it is.  I don't seem to remember any of this when I installed dev tools for previous mac OS upgrades.  Anyone else run into this problem or offer some advice?

The code I'm compling is dirt simple obviously,  file name helloworld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int main() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }
```

Just trying

```
g++ helloworld.cpp
```

and its saying it can't find iostream.h  (no such file or directory)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What gets downloaded from the App Store is an installer for Xcode 4.1.  You then need to manually run the installer.  You should find it in `/Applications`.

Comment: You're not the only one!  It is rather unusual behavior for the App Store. AFAIK, only the Lion installer and the Xcode 4 installer work like that.

Answer (score 8):

The Xcode app just installs the IDE environment, if you want to build also from the command line then do the following:

1. Start the Xcode IDE.
2. From the "Xcode" menu chose "Open Developer Tool" -> "More Developer Tools..."
3. This takes you to a download site where you can download the latest "Command Line Tools for Xcode". Download and install this and you then have the command line environment too. No need to go searching for the tools and changing your path.

Regards,
Simon

Comment: Why would they do such a thing. Frankly, I think g++ should be installed for CLI in general.

Comment: Amazed that CLI tools requires 147MB... Shouldn't it just be a bunch of symbolic links in the right places?

Answer (score 1):

I found the "installers" in 2 packages.

I executed the commands using:

```
open "./Install Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/DeveloperToolsSystemSupport.pkg"
```

and

```
open  "./Install Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Packages/DevSDK.pkg"
```

Answer (score 0):

After running the XCode *installer* that is downloaded by the App Store do the following:

1. Start the Xcode IDE.
2. From the "Xcode" menu chose "Preferences..."
3. Select the "Downloads" section in the Preferences Pane
4. Click install for "Command Line Tools" and you then have the command line environment too. No need to go to other web pages and manually download additional .dmg files.

(this is similar to, but simpler than, Simon's solution)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use gcc 4.2 from Xcode anyways. It is pretty old and not recommended anymore, especially not if you are writing C++11.
For me, and for many other people I am working with, *Macports* worked really well. To install GCC 4.7 for example, simply set up Macports (http://www.macports.org/install.php), and then type the following command into your shell terminal:

```
sudo port install gcc47
```

which will install the compiler in your `/opt/local` directory by default