# C++ Hello World not compiling

Tags: c++

I just recently installed OSX lion and got xcode 4.

I made a file in a directory somewhere and put this code in it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Then I ran gcc filename.cc

and I get these errors:

1.cc:3:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
1.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
1.cc:8: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope

what's wrong?

EDIT:

if I run g++ filename.cc I get the same errors.

1.cc:3:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
1.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
1.cc:8: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Sounds like you've got a problem with your dev environment. I'm running Snow Leopard with Xcode 4 and it compiles fine as expected.

Comment: Can you check what is `g++` on your system? What is the output of `ls -al \`which g++\``? Have you installed it right? There seems to some problem faced during installation... See if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891841/trouble-using-g-after-upgrading-to-lion-new-xcode) helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using gcc? Use g++ instead.

Comment: just uninstalled and reinstalled xcode and it works now. thanks anyways

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your include paths are not set, so iostream is not found. These are normally set automatically - you will need environment variables like INCLUDE=

Or you can set these on the command line like

g++ -i  filename.cc

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
g++ filename.cc
```

You could also try using `clang++`, which will use Apple's new compiler:

```
clang++ filename.cc
```